# Pulling a custom URL from user entered information

Tags: php, forms, variables, submit

So im trying to use the form in this page,

http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/calculation/cakeform.html

but instead of showing the results in the same page, I want the value to be posted onto a php page (via submit button)

i tried the code below but is not capturing any values, neither from the div, neither the submit button. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['search']))
        exit("Error. You have to get here through the search page");

    $destination = "";
    switch($_POST['search')
    {
        case "127234":
            $destination = "127234.com";
            break;

        case "806654":
            $destination = "806654.com";
            break;



        default:  //  

            $destination = "oops.com";
            break;
    }
    header("Location: ".$destination);
    ?>
```

Comment: where is the html and the js? What is the actual result of the page? Is it `Error. You have to get here through the search page`? Is it a blank page?

Comment: HTML page

          <form id="cakeform" action="redirect.php">
         <input onclick="calculateTotal()" type='submit' id='submit' name="search" value=' ' />
         </form>

PHP page 

     <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['search']))
            exit("Error");
        $destination = "";
        switch($_POST['search')
        {
            case "1":
                $destination = "1page.php";
                break;
            default:  // 
                $destination = "error.php";
                break;
        }
        header("Location: ".$destination);
        ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your form contains

```html
<form id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
```

change it to

```html
<form  id="cakeform" action="filename.php">
```

Comment: I have tried the above but the form is still not posting.

Comment: I am able to pass all the variables except the totalPrice 

Cake <?php echo $_POST['selectedcake']; ?><br />
Filling <?php echo $_POST['filling']; ?><br />

Candles <?php echo $_POST['includecandles']; ?><br />

Your name is: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?><br />
Your e-mail: <?php echo $_POST['address']; ?><br />
<br />

Phone Number <?php echo $_POST['phonenumber']; ?><br />
<br />

Total price<br />
<?php echo $_POST['totalPrice']; ?>

Comment: can you give me the content of your files?  maybe the mthod is not there ... try this  <form  id="cakeform" action="filename.php" method="POST">